# Finding multiples of 7 between 2 given integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm trying to return a string (a comma-separated list) of all numbers between two given integers that are multiples of 7. I know how to find the multiples with the modulus operator but not between 2 *given* numbers. I'm new to JS and learning. Help is greatly appreciated.

Starting with something like this:

```
function findMultiplesOfSeven(startNumber, endNumber) { 
  return string;
}
```

Comment: Just search the first multiple from startNumber and then iterate adding 7... when the result is greater than endNumber you have finished.

Comment: A start is nice, but do you have any thoughts on how you could potentially do it? It doesn't even have to be fully in code, just an idea, any effort?

Comment: Ignore the "code" part: if you had to do this on paper, what would you do? Because it makes no sense to start writing code when you don't have a description of what you might even need to do.

Comment: If you are just learning, first write out what you want to do.  Then keep breaking it down until you get pseudo code.  Then write the code.

Comment: @alwayslearning22 why not to do it with jquery instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findMultiplesOfSeven(startNumber, endNumber) {
let containsNumberDivisibleBy7 = false;
let firstNumber;
let numbers = [];
for (var i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; i++) {
    if (i % 7 === 0) {
        containsNumberDivisibleBy7 = true;
        firstNumber = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (containsNumberDivisibleBy7) {
    for (var i = firstNumber; i <= endNumber; i += 7) {
        numbers.push(i);
    }

}
return numbers.join(",");
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could take the start value and add the remainder value for getting the first wanted value.

```
i = startValue + startValue % 7  // 5 + 2 => 7
```

Then iterate and loop until the value is greater then the end value.

```
for (i = startValue + startValue % 7; i <= endValue; i += 7) {
    // add value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sample code:

```
function findMultiplesOfSeven(startNumber, endNumber) {
  let multiples = [];
  let walk = startNumber + (7 - startNumber % 7);
  while(walk <= endNumber) {
    multiples.push(walk);
    walk += 7;
  }
  let string = multiples.join(',')
  return string;
}
```